# Howto check if Ssh.NET connection is established successfully?

Tags: c#, ssh.net

I would like to get to know how Ssh.NET can tell me if the connection is established successfully:

```
SshClient client = new SshClient("127.0.0.1", 22, "root", "");
client.Connect();

// Connection ok? Then continue, else display error

SshCommand x = client.RunCommand("service apache2 status");
client.Disconnect();
client.Dispose();
```

And how do I proof the result of "client.RunCommand("service apache2 status");" logically?
E.g. if(x == "apache2 is running")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check the [`SshClient.IsConnected`](https://sshnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Renci.SshClient/Renci.SshNet/BaseClient.cs) property:

```
if (!client.IsConnected)
{
   // Display error
}
```

Comment: Thanks :-) Sometimes you can not see the forest for the trees.

Comment: Note: I had an issue where I'd kept a connection open but unused for a period of time.  The `IsConnected` returned true, but calling `ListDirectory` restulted in an error (`System.NotSupportedException: Request 'ping' is not supported.`).  This was not fixed using `KeepAliveInterval`.  Instead I had to disconnect the connection after each use to force IsConnected to return false, and thus a new connection be created on each request.  Hope this comment helps someone in future...

Comment: Problem with this that I have is that my code never gets to `if (client.isConnected())`
because it throws an exception and program breaks. How do I loop through a number of clients, and if some of them are off I want the code to just try the next one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use client.IsConnected for this

```
using (var client = new SshClient("127.0.0.1", 22, "root", "")) {
    client.Connect();

    if (client.IsConnected) {
        SshCommand x = client.RunCommand("cd ~");
    } else {
        Console.WriteLine("Not connected");
    }

    client.Disconnect();
}
```

Comment: I added a using on the first line. If the code reaches the end of the using block it'll automatically dispose the var in the using so in this case var client (SshClient)

Answer (score 0):

Try using IsConnected Property

```
If cSSH.IsConnected Then
    Dim x As SshCommand = cSSH.RunCommand("service apache2 status")
    con.Text = "Success"
Else
    con.Text = "Error! Connection Failed"
End If
```